# How to merge array inside the same array

Tags: php

I have this function pager.

```
//Pager: Pagination
//Show next pages box if argument is greater than 20
//We fetching 20 records per page -- Adjust to your needs

    function pager(array $options = array()){
    $options = array_merge(array(
    'NumOfRecords'      => 0, //number of records from database 
    'maxPager'          => 5, //number pager to show eg. 1-5
    'maxPageRecords'    => 20, // since I need 20 records maximum per/page
    'PageFile'            => '' , // indicates the page we're calling pager on
    'method'                  => array_merge(array('global'=>'GET','name'=>'tab_id'),array_column($options, 'method'))          
    ),$options);

    $rows = (int) $options['NumOfRecords'];
    $maxPager = (int) $options['maxPager'];
    $maxPageRecords = (int) $options['maxPageRecords'];
    $pageFile = strtolower($options['PageFile']);
    $method   = $options['method']['global'];
    $method_name = $options['method']['name'];
    }
```

Because I will be calling this pager function on various places of my project I may sometime want to change the method array property values

so I want to have default values...
Now how do i merge the default values plush the ones that I may add later when I call it

I tried it but i can see if one of the default property of the method is not defined it gives me  undefined index.

How do i solve this?

Calling pager this way:

```
pager(array(
            'maxPageRecords'=>$pageSize,
            'NumOfRecords'=>$NumOfRecords, //records could be any number e.g. 400,200..make sure its coming from DB
            'maxPager'=>5,
            'PageFile' => "questions/?page=",
            'method'   => array('name'=>'pager_id')
            ));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function pager(array $new_options = array())
{
    $options = array_merge(array(
        'NumOfRecords'      => 0, //number of records from database 
        'maxPager'          => 5, //number pager to show eg. 1-5
        'maxPageRecords'    => 20, // since I need 20 records maximum per/page
        'PageFile'          => '', // indicates the page we're calling pager on
    ), $new_options);

    $options['method'] = array_merge(array('global'=>'GET','name'=>'tab_id'), $new_options['method'] ?? []);       

    $rows = (int) $options['NumOfRecords'];
    $maxPager = (int) $options['maxPager'];
    $maxPageRecords = (int) $options['maxPageRecords'];
    $pageFile = strtolower($options['PageFile']);
    $method   = $options['method']['global'];
    $method_name = $options['method']['name'];
}
```

[3v4l](https://3v4l.org/geEW7) HERE